# Dart regular expressions for grouping chunks of data

Tags: regex, dart, grouping

I am trying to use regular expressions in Dart to group data chunks that have a similar structure. Following is a sample string that I am using.

```
@prefix : <#>.
@prefix acl: <http://www.w3.org/ns/auth/acl#>.
@prefix c: </profile/card#>.
@prefix c0: <https://anushka.net/profile/card#>.
@prefix c1: <https://isuru.net/profile/card#>.

:ControlReadWrite
    a acl:Authorization;
    acl:accessTo <personal-data.ttl>;
    acl:agent c:me;
    acl:mode acl:Control, acl:Read, acl:Write.
:ReadWrite
    a acl:Authorization;
    acl:accessTo <profile-data.ttl>;
    acl:agent c:me, c0:me;
    acl:mode acl:Read.
:Read
    a acl:Authorization;
    acl:accessTo <medical-data.ttl>, <education-data.ttl>;
    acl:agent c:me, c0:me, c1:me;
    acl:mode acl:Read.
```

I want to divide the above string into the following three groups ignoring the lines which have the word `@prefix`.

```
    a acl:Authorization;
    acl:accessTo <personal-data.ttl>;
    acl:agent c:me;
    acl:mode acl:Control, acl:Read, acl:Write.
```

```
    a acl:Authorization;
    acl:accessTo <profile-data.ttl>;
    acl:agent c:me, c0:me;
    acl:mode acl:Read.
```

```
    a acl:Authorization;
    acl:accessTo <medical-data.ttl>, <education-data.ttl>;
    acl:agent c:me, c0:me, c1:me;
    acl:mode acl:Read.
```

Since each of this group ends with a `.` and `\n`, I tried using `/a acl:Authorization([a-zA-Z;<>\n: -0-9]\.\n)/` but that did not work. Any help resolving this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with recognizing the `:SomeWords` as the start, recognize `;` as separator and `.` as end.

Something like

```dart
var re = RegExp(r"(?<=^:[a-zA-Z]+\n)(?:^\s+.*;$\n)*(?:^\s+.*\.\n)", 
  multiLine: true);
```

This matches lines starting with space and ending with `;` or (for the last one) `.`, and preceded by a line of `:SomeWords`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. This worked perfectly. I just had to include `?` at the end because in the last group there is no line break. So my final regex is `r"(?<=^:[a-zA-Z]+\n)(?:^\s+.*;$\n)*(?:^\s+.*\.\n?)"`